# Contribution analysis versus lca.score

Tags: brightway

I am interested in which processes/activities contribute most to the Life Cycle Impact Assessment (LCIA) that I am conducting. For this, I run a contribution analysis (see code below). To crosscheck the results of my contribution analysis and to ensure that I get everything right, I wanted to compare the returned contributions with the impact assessment result (`lca.score`).

The documentation of `ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)` says: "Returns a list of tuples: `(lca score, supply, activity)`."

In my understanding, `lca.score` should be the same value as the sum of all the first values in the tuples that are returned by `ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)` (the printed values). However, this is not the case. What am I missing? Is there some sort of cut-off applied or did I misunderstand something?

```py
import bw2analyzer as bwa

random_act = db_ei381.random()

lca = bw2data.LCA(
    {random_act: 1},
    ('ReCiPe Midpoint (H) V1.13', 'water depletion', 'WDP')
    )

lca.lci()
lca.lcia()

print(lca.score)

# %% Contribution analysis

ca = bwa.ContributionAnalysis()

contributions = ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)

print(sum([i[0] for i in contributions]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not well documented, but you can introduce an argument `limit` that specifies the number of activities that are considered in the contribution analysis. The default value I think is 25. It is sorted so the most important activities come first. If you write something like this you should see how the result converges to the total score as the number of activities increase:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cutoff = [25,50,100,500,1000,1200]

scores = []
for n in cutoff:

    contributions = ca.annotated_top_processes(lca,limit=n)
    contr_sum = sum([i[0] for i in contributions])
    scores.append(contr_sum)

plt.plot(cutoff,scores)
plt.axhline(lca.score,ls='--',color='r');
```

Comment: Thanks Nabla! Great help!